# Async GLKit's GLKViewController replacement (async OpenGL drawing)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, grand-central-dispatch, glkit

As per this [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850809/how-to-draw-to-glkits-opengl-es-context-asynchronously-from-a-grand-central-dis) `GLKViewController` is not really compatible with the async OpenGL drawing mode.

Does anybody know of any open source or code sample reimplementing `GLKViewController` (`UIViewController` subclass) but with more manual controls so it can be used together with async drawing?

Answer (score 1):

This question is simply too broad. You are looking for a sample with more manual controls? You should be much more specific on what you are looking for.

I don't know many good sources or samples that implement something of relatively as high level as a view controller but I do know a few very good procedures on how to separate your modules to have a great support for the asynchronous usage of the openGLES on the iOS.

For a detailed description on how to port the `GLKViewController` you should list the items you are already using or rather items you are having trouble getting the answer to on the web. Unfortunately my opinion on using both `GLKViewController` and `GLKView` is simply "Don't!".

So about that module separation for multithreading what I use is a class that wraps the context and is initialized with a thread and optionally with another context wrapper to support sharing between the contexts. How this wrapper works is that every method that is called on the wrapper is passed to be performed on the thread that the wrapper is bound to. To addition it also contains methods `performBlock:` and `performBlock:callback:` which will perform the block on the bound thread and optionally call another block once complete.

From here on this wrapper is further subclassed to contain the current context states (for the optimizations), include loaded shaders pool (cache) and a loaded texture pool (cache). The shared wrappers are also linked to their parent with which they were created so only parents contain the pools.

So the procedure for loading the texture in background would look something like that:

- Starting only with `mainContext`
- Create a `newThread`
- Create a `sharedContext` from the `mainContext` and the `newThread`
- Request the `mainContext` to create a `texture` (just to get the ID)
- On completion request the `sharedContext` to load the texture data to the `texture` and notify the `mainContext` when done.
- Do what you want with the `texture` and delete the `sharedContext` or rather keep it for later usage.

Now I hope you can see with this procedure you may easily create a higher level system where for the most common case you would create a class containing two context wrappers, the main context and the background worker. This type of system should be extremely easy to maintain and from the usage perspective you will never need to worry about the multithreading.

After that to get pretty near to the `GLKViewController` I have a class containing a frame buffer and render buffers which is initialized either with an `UIView` for displaying or initialized with a size which generates a texture and is used for FBO system. So having a view controller that includes this class and the context wrapper can be quite a powerful tool which kind of seems something like you may need.

If you choose to implement this sort of a system and encounter any issues I would be glad to hear about it and help you or rather yet hear about your success.